# SharePoint Webservice from Java Webapp using CXF with Kerberos/NTLM authentication

Tags: java, web-services, sharepoint, cxf, kerberos

I have a Java EE web application from the web app I have to consume a SharePoint web-service which expects Kerberos/NTLM authentication how can I achieve. I am using CXF for consuming web-service and the web application it self uses Windows Integrated Authentication for authentication.

Comment: Do you want to consume webservice which uses Kerberos Token Profile 1.1? CXF supports this [out of the box](http://domagojtechtips.blogspot.com/2007/08/cxf-spring-and-ws-security-putting-it.html), you need to configure the right [interceptor](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/rt/ws/security/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/ws/security/wss4j/policyvalidators/KerberosTokenPolicyValidator.java?view=markup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the SPNEGO protocol,  this is what Sharepoint  ( technically IIS ) uses for Single Sign On authentication.  I am not familar with CXF,  but generally most of the WebServices platforms allow you to supply additional headers with your request.  Basically what you need is:

```
1.  Get authentication token for the sharepoint from user session  

2.  Use JAAS to generate tokens.
```

Look here http://appliedcrypto.com/spnego/spnego_jaasclient.html and here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/lab/part6.html for more details.

For the case when you want to authenticate browser users to sharepoint.  You have to implement SPNEGO protocol in your web app for example you can use [this](http://waffle.codeplex.com/) package do it you.  Most of the modern app servers support SPNEGO protocol  [ JBoss, WebSphere ].   After you implemented SPNEGO protocol,  you can grab the kerberos token from 'Authorization'  header.

Then you have two options:

1. In case you run your web-app with the same identity as the SharePoint front-end you can just resend the same token to the sharepoint.
2. In case you running as a different identity,  you have to use the user's token to go to active directory and request a ticket for sharepoint service on behalf of your user.  The account that your web-app runs under has to be trusted for delegation in Active Directory

Also,  I am not sure that SharePoint accepts kerberos tokens within SOAP headers, I believe you have to authenticate using HTTP headers.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534278/configure-tomcat-for-ad-kerberos-impersonating) question might help you

If you want to use single sign on feature meaning using current user identity take a look 
[here](http://dmdaa.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/kerberos-setup-and-jaas-configuration-for-running-sun-jgss-tutorial-against-ad/)

Comment: all the link that you mentioned for accessing from java desktop client but my requirement is I want to access the web-service from a web application. The authentication credential for the web-service should be the credential of the web application user. Is there any way to attach the kerberos token in the SOAP header?

Comment: Thanks Vlad the mistake we were doing was adding the token to SOAP header after using HTTP header it worked. Thanks a lot